What show did Yakko, Wakko, and Dot make frequent silent cameos in?
Animaniacs was an animated TV show made in the 90's about the Warner siblings, Yakko, Wakko, and Dot.  But I don't think that is the only TV show I've seen Yakko, Wakko, and Dot in.  I have a distinct memory of these three characters appearing in another 90's animated TV show, where they were often shown running around, with no dialogue.  Can someone help me identify it?
At least my recollection is that the  show is Tiny Toon Adventures.  Now Tiny Adventures ran from 1990 to 1992, whereas Animaniacs ran from 1993 to 1998.  But they were both Warner Bros. shows, so it's possible that toward the end of the Tiny Toon Adventures run they were showing cameos of Animaniacs characters to lead into the new show.  Can anyone confirm this?
Now it's possible that I'm misremembering, and the show I'm thinking of is actually Pinky and the Brain.  After all, Pinky and the Brain was a spinoff of Animaniacs, so it makes sense that you would have Animaniacs cameos in Pinky and the Brain.

They might also have appeared in Freakazoid, another related show.

Found out they often cameo in Rita and Runt as well. Although the most likely appeared in Freakazoid and all Warner Animations of that time.
